# SQLException: unable to open database file - Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, sqlite, file-permissions

I have a problem with permission on Windows 7 with SQLite and Java. Everything works fine when debuging from Eclipse. When I try to run the relase application, I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: unable to open database file
at org.sqlite.DB.execute(DB.java:275)
at org.sqlite.DB.executeUpdate(DB.java:281)
at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeUpdate(Stmt.java:103)
at com.project.application.Dao.reinit(Dao.java:38)
```

The data are stored in c:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\\data\ and the app is able to write config giles in the same directory.

Strange is, that when I start the app as "Run as administrator" the application works!

Comment: The user that launchs the application doesn't have enough permissions to write files in that folder, that's why you get the error.

Comment: I'm able to write there config files and other stuff, so the app have permissions to write in that folder ...